# Outlook (on Exchange) rules - how can I use the OR operator?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, rules

In my organization I'm a member of many distribution lists, I have a rule for each DL/ML such that each message is delivered to a subfolder for that DL, however it's important that any messages sent to a distribution list, but containing my name in the `To:`, `Cc:`, or in the message body are delivered to my Inbox and not my distribution list subfolders.

I have a rule set up in my Exchange (Office 365) account that looks like this:

- Apply this rule after the message arrives
- Where my name is in the To box

  - and where my name is in the Cc box
  - and where my name is in the To or Cc box
  - and with "Dai" in the body
- move it to the `Inbox` folder

  - and stop processing more rules

At first-glance, this rule seems fine - except that it applies the `AND` operator, so logically only messages with my name *simultaneously* in `To`, `Cc`, and the body will be moved to my inbox. Surprisingly this does happen - but it means that a lot of messages fall through the cracks.

Rather than creating one rule for each, is there a way to change it so these predicates are applied with the `OR` operator instead of `AND`?

I'm using Office 365 Exchange so I can't use VBA rules (which, in my understanding, run on the client).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of a way. Outlook rules are pretty limited, it's too bad they don't have an advanced RegEx method to create rules.
I think you'll have to fall back on your three rules idea.

Or open a suggestion to MS.